# Fail to install RPM package due to libstdc++ version

Tags: rpm, libstdc++

When I install an RPM package, it prompted wrong message that was dependencies problem of libstdc++.so.6.  My OS is CentOS 7.9 and gcc version is 11.

[root@dist]# rpm -hiv TCGstorageAPI-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm

error: Failed dependencies:

libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.9)(64bit) is needed by TCGstorageAPI-1.0-1.x86_64

libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.21)(64bit) is needed by TCGstorageAPI-1.0-1.x86_64

libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.26)(64bit) is needed by TCGstorageAPI-1.0-1.x86_64

libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.29)(64bit) is needed by TCGstorageAPI-1.0-1.x86_64

But I have put newer libstdc++.so.6.0.29 into /lib64 and /usr/lib64 folders and created right soft link to libstdc++.so.6.   libstdc++.so.6.0.29 supports CXXABI_1.3.9 and GLIBCXX_3.4.29.  I don't know why still report dependencies error. Could you someone help me take a look? Thanks

[root@dist]# strings /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.29 | grep GLIBCXX_3.4.29

GLIBCXX_3.4.29

GLIBCXX_3.4.29

[root@dist]# ls /usr/lib64/libstdc++* -l

lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root       19 Dec 22 15:30 /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so -> libstdc++.so.6.0.29

lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root       19 Dec 22 15:30 /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.29

-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   995840 Sep 30  2020 /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.19

-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 16757720 Jan 10  2022 /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.28

-rw-r--r--. 1 root root     2386 Jan 10  2022 /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.28-gdb.py

-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 14608032 Dec 22 15:30 /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.29

-rw-r--r--. 1 root root     2382 Dec 22 15:30 /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.29-gdb.py

[root@dist]# ls /lib64/libstdc++* -l

lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root       19 Dec 22 15:30 /lib64/libstdc++.so -> libstdc++.so.6.0.29

lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root       19 Dec 22 15:30 /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.29

-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   995840 Sep 30  2020 /lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.19

-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 16757720 Jan 10  2022 /lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.28

-rw-r--r--. 1 root root     2386 Jan 10  2022 /lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.28-gdb.py

-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 14608032 Dec 22 15:30 /lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.29

-rw-r--r--. 1 root root     2382 Dec 22 15:30 /lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.29-gdb.py

Comment: Did you build from source or grab an RPM from somewhere?  If from source, did you follow **all** the instructions at https://github.com/Seagate/TCGstorageAPI/blob/master/README.md  If you grabbed that RPM from somewhere, are you **certain** it was built for Centos 7 and not Centos/RHEL 8?

Comment: yes, I totally followed the instructions from TCGstorageAPI project to build the source code. After compiling, it would generate rpm pakages which needs to be installed to python library folder. When installing this rpm package, failed message occur.